# css place the items in div class

Tags: html, css

I want:

```
                    block

           block1  block2 block2
```

where

```
block ="head"
block1="h1"
block2="search box"
block3="itembox"
```

I want to put them in side by side..
I have tried below code in jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm8044a8/)

but here these blocks not coming in same line.

Comment: You have not the markup in your fiddle as described. Set `#search{float:left}` and you have them on same line.

Answer (score 1):

don't use **head** tag use `header` for that

try this

```
 #search {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dm8044a8/2/

Answer (score 1):

The  element can include a title for the document, scripts, styles, meta information, and more.Head is not used inside inside BODY.

Use [header](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp) instead tag.
I don't understand `<itembox>` tag. Are u using any framework?. I think you want some thing like this. Please change the width value as per your requirement.

```css
header {
 background: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 76px;
 position: fixed;
    
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #7e7e7e;
 z-index: 100;
  display:flex;
  
  
}

header h1{
 
 color: #ff0;
 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg,#f35626,#feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
    text-align:center;
  flex-direction: column; 
     
    
}





#search {
 float: left;
 
    width: auto;
 height: 40px;
  flex-direction: column; 
    
}

.itembox {
 float: left;
 background:green;
  flex-direction: column; 
}


 #search input {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
 border: 0 none;
 color: #7F7F7F;
 float: left;
 font: 12px 'Helvetica','Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
 height: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 width: 300px;
}

#search button {
 background: url("search.png") no-repeat scroll center center #7eac10;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 40px;
 text-indent: -99999em;
 transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 width: 40px;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
}

#search button:hover {
 background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>news </h1>

  <div id="search">
    <form method="post" id="search" action="#">

      <input type="text" class="search" value="Type and hit enter" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Type and hit enter'; }" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Type and hit enter') { this.value = ''; }" name="s">
      <button type="submit" style="display:inline-block;">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="itembox">Item box</div>
  </div>




</header>
```

Comment: yes that will be the header..and these 3 blocks needs to be same line.  h1,searchbox then the itembox..same line

Comment: best one to do is display :flex, Updated answer.